# How to customise the invite dialog sheet in Firebase Invites for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-invites

I have integrated the Firebase Invites in my App, which provides only two options SMS & Email.
Now I want to share the dynamic link via whatsapp and other social networking channel like facebook and Twitter.
I didn't find any solution on developer site.
I have seen some solution for customization of share sheet but for android.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think it's cannot be possible in iOS. I'll let you know if I'll get done it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the enough R&D on the this and finally reached to a point that this is not possible.
Firebase only provides only two options i.e mail and text message 
Apart from that no other options are available .
I don't understand why they have mentioned in Fire-doc that we can customise the ShareSheet , but we can't do anything like that.

I suggest everyone not to waste the time on searching for solution.